# Call C# function from Javascript in aspx webform and then reload page

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms

Trying to figure out how to call a c# function in a webform. I tried both ajax and windows.location but could just be off on my path. Trying to send it my c# code at SpeakerList.aspx/update and then gonna attach two variables i have in javascript which shouldnt be too bad. But want it to hit the C# function then reload the page so hoping there is just an easy call im missing.

```
 buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        var combo = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName('DropDownList1');
                        var value = combo.GetSelectedItem().value;
                        var billID = $("#billID").val();
                        window.location = "SpeakerList.aspx/updateRec";
                    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Does the function *need* to be in the webform? Couldn't it exist somewhere else, like in a separate web service?

Comment: If you actually want to "reload the page" that is what your normally get with a page postback on a webform, if you just want to update something on you page, that is usually an ajax call. Can you be more clear what you are having trouble with.

Comment: just posted my current attempt. Well I have the values in javascript and want to get them to my controler. And in my jquery dialog box the button was not firing so figured javascript would be simple and turned out to be giving me trouble. And none of my javascript will find the action.

Comment: You mention a controller, so you are presumably using MVC not webforms. If so, should fix the tags.

Comment: Ya controller is not the right word sorry Im used to mvc but there having me do it in webforms. So whatever the code-behind of a webform is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using WebMethods:

http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.all

This allows you to call a function in your page's code behind using JavaScript.

Comment: I used one very similar to this and it worked pretty good thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MVC, you probably want to return a JSON result. An easy way to consume Json within your client webpage is using JQuery. You can return JSON as as the output of a webpage, but I don't recommend it. Create a separate service point that repesents the JSON method.

It is hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish, but the normal usage pattern for a JSON method is the supply the parameters as part of the querystring (which you can refactor with routing if you want). The result is then just a JSON packet.

Personally, I like JSON.Net for server side JSON, but you don't actually need this. Look up JSONMethod for examples, etc. that will show you how to do this.

From the browser client, JQuery has a json method, but I personally recommend using the more generic ajax method a JQuery so you can use the handlers for success, error and completion. E.g.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http:...",
    data: queryparm,
    cache:false,
    timeout:15000,
    success: function(data){
      jresult = $.parseJSON(data);
      ...
    },

    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
      setErrorMsg("Error getting search results: " + thrownError);
    } 
  });
```

EDIT -- Actually, I've done this exact same thing with webforms too, code is essentially identically (if you use JSON.Net on the server side). You don't have the routing options to make the urls REST compliant, but as an internal json web service, you probably won't really care about that.

As a webpage (.aspx) page, you can use a "postback" this is the simplest method for a web form. You can always declare some hidden fields to use for data passing if you are not passing back a native "control" value. If you don't know how to do this, you need to read a tutorial on using web forms.